# Using Datediff() on Joined Tables with CASES

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to determine the best way to calculate a datediff (in minutes). I'm trying to determine the time lapsed between two stages in a registration process (stage 8 and stage 10), but I only need this for anyone who's ever been in stage 10. There are two tables: Registration and Registrationstagehistory which are linked by the registration id number (rid)

I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

from below.

```
Select datediff(Minute,startdate,enddate)
from Registration r with(nolock)
inner join registrationstagehistory rh with(nolock) on r.rid=rh.rhrid
```

It may be something like this:

```
 CASE WHEN R.RsID=10 THEN
        CASE rh.rhrsid
            WHEN 8 then 'startdate'
            WHEN 10 THEN 'enddate'
        ELSE NULL
    END
END
```

Comment: can you add table schema?

Comment: You're missing an `end` for the outer `CASE` in the code you posted.

Comment: do you only want diffdate(stage 8, stage 10) of registrations that has stage 10?  no more fields?

Comment: @mcNets Yes, but Registration only records a static stage value, where as Registrationstagehistory shows time points for each stage change.

Comment: @MartinSmith I edited the original post, same error message.

Comment: Because the easiest way is to select only records with stage=10 and calculate dadediff with the date of stage 8.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an END to one of your CASE statements (the inner one it appears but i can't be sure from the context I have):

```
CASE WHEN R.RsID=10 THEN
    CASE rh.rhrsid
        WHEN 8 then 'startdate'
        WHEN 10 THEN 'enddate'
        ELSE NULL
    END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it here: http://rextester.com/BHBZ30100

I've used this schema for this answer:

```
create table #reg (id int, other text);
create table #his (reg_id int, rs_id int,  rdate datetime);
insert into #reg values (1, 'registration 1'), (2, 'registration 2');
insert into #his values  (1, 1, '2016-11-01')
                        ,(1, 5, '2016-11-05')
                        ,(1, 8, '2016-11-08')
                        ,(1, 9, '2016-11-09')
                        ,(1,10, '2016-11-10')
                        ,(2, 1, '2016-11-01')
                        ,(2, 5, '2016-11-05');
```

If you only want the `datediff` in RegistrationHistory table of Registration records that has reached Stage 10, you can directly filter the records where `Stage=10`. Then use another query to search the date of Stage 8, and find the difference.

```
select 
    #reg.*, #his.*,
    datediff( minute 
              ,isnull((select h2.rdate
                     from #his h2
                     where h2.rs_id = 8 and h2.reg_id = #his.reg_id), #his.rdate)
              ,#his.rdate) as minutes         
from #his
    inner join #reg on #his.reg_id = #reg.id
where 
    #his.rs_id = 10
```

And this is the result: (I've added all fields, due I don't know exactly what you need),

```
+----+----+----------------+--------+-------+---------------------+---------+
|    | id | other          | reg_id | rs_id | rdate               | minutes |
+----+----+----------------+--------+-------+---------------------+---------+
| 1  | 1  | registration 1 | 1      | 10    | 10.11.2016 00:00:00 | 2880    |
+----+----+----------------+--------+-------+---------------------+---------+
```